# How to move lightroom catalog to a new drive

Tags: macos, adobe, lightroom

I use adobe lightroom for all my photos and I am constantly running into space issues.  I have been told not to move my lightroom files by several individuals.  Why is that?  Surely there must be a way to move a lightroom catalog from one drive to another drive with no adverse effects.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This may help.  It talks a lot about "archiving", but moving folders of photos to another drive sounds like what you're trying to do: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adobe-evangelists-julieanne-kost/questions-about-lightroom-and-photo-management/

Here's a step-by-step description of the process in text, not a video: http://digital-photography-school.com/moving-a-lightroom-catalog

Hope this helps...